# How to go from a normal inequality to prove a tuple inequality?

Tags: functions

I got this question for an assignment I have to prove (or disprove) this following function is injective:
$$g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, \ g(x) = (3x, 7)$$
I know that the definition of injectivity is $f(x_1) = f(x_2) \implies x_1 = x_2$ so I just do a contrapositive that results in $x_1 \neq x_2 \implies f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$.

Well I assume that $x_1 \neq x_2$ which leads us to $3x_1 \neq 3x_2$ and so far I think the steps are right. Once I realize that I have to prove $(3x_1, 7) \neq (3x_2, 7)$ I do not know how to turn a single variable inequality into a tuple inequality.

Maybe I missed some conditions that needs to be fulfilled but I am not sure.

Comment: $(a,b) \ne (c,d) \iff a \ne c$ or $b \ne d.$

Comment: @Fred so from what I understood, because $b = d = 7$ the $\vee$ becomes irrelevant and $a \neq c$ is my way to go?

Comment: Yes, $(3x_1, 7) \neq (3x_2, 7) \iff x_1 \ne x_2.$